# How can I successively add multiple lines to a graph in a plotly animation?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly, line-plot

I want to show multiple lines being added to a plotly plot (as an animation) using R. For example, I have the following plotly line graphs (`p, p2, p3)`:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(3)
x = 1:10
y = 1:10
y2 = y^2
y3 = y^3
p = plot_ly(data = data.frame(x = x, y = y), x = ~ x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
p2 = plot_ly(data = data.frame(x = x, y = y2), x = ~ x, y = ~y2, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
p3 = plot_ly(data = data.frame(x = x, y = y3), x = ~ x, y = ~y3, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
```

Here `p, p2, p3` are different plots but they all have the same `x` axis and different `y` axis. I want to be able to make an animation where the lines `y, y2, y3` will successively appear in the plotly graph.

P.S: It does not strictly have to be done using `plotly`, but strongly preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea might be to create a 'dataset' for each frame.
The first frame contains all values for y and all values for y2 and y3 are located outside the y-axis limits. For the second frame all values from y and y2 are shown and just the values from y3 are beyond the limit. In frame 3 all values are included.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# transform dataframe into a long format
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = 1:10) %>%
  mutate(y2 = y^2,
         y3 = y^3) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -x,
               names_to = "line",
               values_to = "value")

# set the values for each frame and line 
# (all lines not shown, need to hidden outside the plot limits - NA won't work)
df_plot <- map_df(1:3,  ~ mutate(df, frame = .)) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(frame == 1 & line %in% c("y2", "y3") ~ -10,
                           frame == 2 & line %in% c("y3") ~ -10,
                           TRUE ~ value))

# create plot
plot_ly(data = df_plot, 
        x = ~x,
        y = ~value,
        color = ~line,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "line",
        frame = ~frame)  %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(range = c(0, 1000))) %>%
  animation_opts(easing = "bounce")
```

Comment: it sounds very promising! Would you please edit the comment and add the packages that you used? Currently it is not possible to reproduce the plot (probably due to some function from a package that I have not installed)

Comment: @bird the packages are now included on top of the code

Comment: The code works beautifully! Thanks a lot! :)